# Defining a nested class out of line in C++

Tags: c++, inner-classes, forward-declaration

Sorry if this has been asked before; I found similarly titled questions, but none of them focused on the same aspects I'm having trouble with.

There's a class A, and a class B that should only be accessible from A. I think nesting B inside A will achieve that, but I'm struggling with the logistics.

A has a B as a member. As such, not defining B prior to declaring A's members causes incomplete type errors. I thought I'd get around this by declaring A, defining A::B, then defining A, but that just throws the same errors plus `incomplete type 'A' in nested name specifier`.

```
class A;

class A::B
{
    ...
};

class A
{
private:
    class B;
    B b;
    ...
};
```

The only functional examples I can find would put B's member declaration directly *inside* A's, which I'd really like to avoid doing: B's header information is several times longer and much denser than A's. Splitting the two up into separate files would be best, but actually nesting them inline is incredibly unwieldy.

Fallback options at this point include making A's B a pointer (no real reason why not, but is this really something that can't be done?) and leaving them as independent classes. But surely this can't be that hard?

What do I need to declare to link these properly and in what order?

**I am not particularly knowledgeable** about the depths of C++ so please explain like I'm five and refrain from shaming me into the ground for not knowing everything.

Comment: IMHO, nested classes only cause trouble.  Don't nest classes.  Nesting makes reuse more difficult.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews B is already tailored to the specifics of A and wouldn't be reusable without modification. That's really why I want to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One particularly non-convoluted way of doing this would be

```
class B
{
   friend class A;
   private:
    // everything;
};

class A
{
  B b;
};
```

This of course makes all the guts of B accessible to A, bit if B is such A-specific, it should not be a problem.

If this is not desirable, a slightly wore windy path to a solution would be

```
class PreA
{
   protected:
      class B { ... };
};

class A : PreA
{
   B b;
};
```

Comment: Not perfect, but good enough. Thanks for actually reading the question, and the second solution is one I wouldn't have thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Since `b` is a **non-reference non static data member** of class `A`, it must be declared to have a complete type.

One way to solve this would be to either make `b` a reference type(as shown below) or a pointer to a `B`:

```
class A
{
private:
    class B;
//--vv------------>now b is an lvalue reference to a B object
    B& b;   
};


class A::B
{
    
};
```

---

##### Method 2

Other option is to define `B` inside `A` with only its member **declaration** and then define those members outside as shown below:

```
class A
{
private:
    //defined class now 
    class B
    {
         void member1();
    };

    B b;      //works now 
};

void A::B::member1()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned both those solutions.

Answer (score -1):

> The only functional examples I can find would put B's member
> declaration directly inside A's, which I'd really like to avoid doing:
> B's header information is several times longer and much denser than
> A's. Splitting the two up into separate files would be best, but
> actually nesting them inline is incredibly unwieldy.

The premise is interesting until I saw this comment of yours, I assume by you mean "Hide" is "Hide the Code it Self", not the members and method of B?

> B is already tailored to the specifics of A and wouldn't be reusable
> without modification. That's really why I want to hide it.

And with this line, can I assume that you aren't familiar with the concept of inheritance?

> I am not particularly knowledgeable about the depths of C++ so please
> explain like I'm five and refrain from shaming me into the ground for
> not knowing everything.

You can simply inherit Class A into Class B, then use Class B itself? or the other way around. Just remember that the Base Class *[Class A in this Case]* has no idea what methods or member the Derived Class has *[Class B in this Case]*.

e.g.*All (Derived)Airplanes can (Base)Fly but not everything that can Fly is an airplane*.

[A Little Introduction to Inheritance can be found here.](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/inheritance) and if you do decide to go through this route, please Read up on a lot of materials about it. It's a Deep hole.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        std::cout << "A's Default Constructor Used " << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A(){std::cout<<"A's Destructor called" << std::endl;};
    int x;
    int y;
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){}
    B(int nX, int nY){x=nX,y=nY;}
    ~B(){std::cout<<"B's Destructor Called"<<std::endl;}
public:
    void SomeMethod(int nX){x+=nX;}
};

int main() {

    B b;
    std::cout << b.x << " " << b.y << std::endl;
    b.SomeMethod(10);
    std::cout << b.x << " " << b.y << std::endl;

}
```

**NOTE:** On A's destructor [`virtual ~A(){std::cout<<"A's Destructor called" << std::endl;};`] the keyword `virtual` is not needed unless you are deleting / destroying Class B from a Pointer to an Object of Class A, and **Absolutely** necessary if you are, Like Below.

```
B* b = new B;
std::cout << b->x << " " << b->y << std::endl;
b->SomeMethod(10);
std::cout << b->x << " " << b->y << std::endl;
A* a = b;
delete a;
```

Without the `virtual` keyword, only A's Destructor would be called and not B's.

Unless inheritance is out of the question then Nesting(Which I personally don't recommend it's a big pain on maintenance) ,creating a pointer of Class B inside A.
Or simply create Class B inside Class A like below.

```
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        z = 0;
        std::cout<<"B Default Constructor Used"<<std::endl;
    }
    B(int nZ)
    {
        z = nZ;
        std::cout<<"B Constructed"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~B(){}
public:
    void SomeMethod(int& nX,int nY){nX += ( nY + z );}
    int z;
};
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        std::cout << "A Default constructor used" << std::endl;
    }
    
    A(int nX,int nY,int nZ)
    {
        x = nX;
        y = nY;
        b.z = nZ;
        std::cout << "A's Constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A(){};
    B b;
    int x;
    int y;
};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.b.SomeMethod(a.x,10);
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl << std::endl;
    // Ore something like this;
    A a2 = A(1,2,3);
    a2.b.SomeMethod(a2.x,20);
    std::cout << a2.x << std::endl;
}
```

Just remember to create a Default Constructor for Class B since it would be called during the creation of Class B. Take note that I am speaking from my personal Experience and Knowledge, and by no means is it gospel, specially when I am self taught, and Using conventions that I am using in my own projects.

Declaring a Class static is one way to prevent Class B's Creation as Well but able to use it's functions . But I rarely find the need to do this in productions. I've mainly used this in debugging things. Since I've only seen it used in C#, and I've never tried it using it in production since I don't know what kind of behavior it could produce.

```
#include <iostream>
static struct B
{
protected:
        B(){};
public:
    static void PrintSomething(int x)
    {
        std::cout <<"Printing Something " << x <<std::endl;
    }
    static void MultiplyBy2(int* x)
    {
        int Two = 2;
        *x = *x * Two;
    }
};
class A
{
public:
    A(int nX,int nY):X(nX),Y(nY){}
public:
    int GetX()const{return X;}
    int GetY()const{return Y;}
    int* PointerToX() {return &X;}
private:
    int X;
    int Y;
};

int main()
{
    A a(1,2);
    B::PrintSomething(a.GetX());
    B::MultiplyBy2(a.PointerToX());
    B::PrintSomething(a.GetX());
    B::MultiplyBy2(a.PointerToX());
    B::PrintSomething(a.GetX());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept, and while there may well be a better solution than what I'm doing, inheritance isn't it—an A isn't a B and a B isn't an A. B is a tool facilitating A's operations on itself. Can you tell me how your last code example prevents B from being constructed outside of A?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you My Second Example will allow B to be constructed outside of A since it is a separate class, since when you've said "Hide" I thought it meant "Hide the Code.". Can you Give me an Example on how exactly will B be used for A?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you If it mainly consists of functions , You can Create a Static Class this way it can't be created but can be used. I'll edit my Answer with an Example.